# Prove that inversion sampling algorithm works

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

I used the inversion method to find an algorithm that can generate pareto-distributed pseudo-random numbers, by first acknowledging that the pareto distribution is $$ f(x)=\frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} $$ where $x_0>0, \alpha >0$ are the scale and shape parameters respectively.

The algorithm is basically to 1) Draw $u \sim U[0,1]$, and 2) $x=F^{-1}(u)$, where we get $F^{-1}(u)$ from

$$ F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(y) dy=1-\Big( \frac{x_0}{x} \Big)^\alpha \implies x=F^{-1}(u)=\frac{x_0}{(1-u)^{1/\alpha}} $$

Step 1 of the algorithm is very basic, and step 2 is now finished since we have derived a formula for $x$, depending on $u$. But how do I prove that the output of the algorithm is pareto distributed, as desired? I thought of inserting the $x$ into the expression for $f(x)=f(\frac{x_0}{(1-u)^{1/\alpha}})$, but that didn't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof (for any cumulative distribution function $F$) can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Proof_of_correctness). In your case you don't need to take the infinum in the definition of $F^{-1}$, since your density is strictly positive and thereby $F$ is bijective (if defined on $[x_0,\infty)$), so things get even simpler.

The proof shows that your constructed random variable $F^{-1}(u)$ has the correct cumulative distribution function and thereby the correct density.

Comment: Hey and thanks for helping out. So basically the proof is $Pr(F^{-1}(u) \leq x) = Pr(u \leq F(x))=F(x)$? In this expression I don't really understand why we start out with $Pr(F^{-1}(u) \leq x)$.

Comment: You start out with $F_X(x) := Pr(X\le x) = Pr(F^{-1}(U)\le x)$, because this is by definition the CDF of your random variable $X=F^{-1}(U)$ (better use capital letters for the random variables $X,U$, makes it easier to distinguish from $x$ in the function $F(x)$ etc.). You want to verify if $X$ has the correct CDF, namely F.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to get it. So because I defined the algorithm the way I did, and since we want to use the CDF for F, we already know that the CDF is defined as $F_X (x)= Pr(X \leq x) = Pr(F^{-1}(U) \leq x)$, where we have replaced $X=F^{-1}(u)$ because that's the way the algorithm works. Then to prove that this is true, I have to go show that $Pr( F^{-1} (u) \leq x)=...=F(x)$, because then I have shown that my assumptions are true. It's a bit confusing because it's like going around a circle. One last q - why didn't we use $x_0$ in this proof, how come it doesn't come in anywhere?

Comment: I would rather say "... and since we want $X$ to have the CDF $F$ ..." and "...because then I have shown that my assertion is true...".

The easiest way to answer your last question is to say that $X$ is only defined on $[x_0,\infty]$. Then $F$ is bijective and everything is simple. Otherwise you would need to define $f(x) =\frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$ for $x\ge x_0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, but everything works out the same way. $x_0$ is just a parameter of your density and therefore of the CDF and of your algorithm. Everything works for every $x_0$.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to study your answers a bit before I'm completely onboard, but big thanks for helping out, giving you the green mark! :)